# Which camera should I buy? DLSR or SLR

Tags: dslr, camera-recommendation, slr

I'm planning to buy a camera for myself, where I came across the term DSLR and SLR.

I'm a novice in photography thus, not knowing the actual meaning of both the term.

Would like to know more about the ***use of DLSR/SLR camera's***, and which one I should buy?

Comment: you're actually comparing shooting film vs digital

Comment: Possibly see: [What do I need to consider to choose between dSLR, mirrorless, or a compact as my first “serious” camera?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67987) dSLR/SLRs aren't the _only_ way to go.

Comment: Related: [With which film camera should I start?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/76985/15871) The accepted answer discusses the advantages for beginners of learning with digital compared to film.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**SLR (Single Lens Reflex)** is an old form of cameras which use film to form images. SLR cameras offer slightly better quality of color, tone and contrast.

**DSLR (Digital Single Lens Reflex)**  refers to SLR cameras that take digital photos. DSLR cameras are great for budding photographers because they offer live previews and do not waste film when photographers make mistakes. There are more DSLRs available in the market so they tend to be cheaper.

Recommendation: You should buy a DSLR.

[Here](http://www.diffen.com/difference/DSLR_vs_SLR_Camera) and [also here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-a-DSLR-and-a-SLR-digital-camera) you can find quick differences between both.

Comment: You can get good used film SLRS for less than $50 USD. I don't think any working DSLR will be cheaper.

Comment: "...slightly better color, tone, and contrast?" When you can shoot raw digital files and then custom correct the color, tone, and contrast of each frame in post? That's the equivalent of having a separate customized film emulsion for every single shot you take! Maybe a decade or more ago if the choice was between film (that can be normalized in the lab when printing from negatives) or JPEG files straight from camera when shooting using auto white balance. But today? Not a chance.

Answer (score 5):

All DSLRs are also SLRs. SLR is an acronym for Single Lens Reflex. The "D" in DSLR is for Digital. SLRs have been around for over half a century. First as film cameras and then more recently also as digital cameras. For more, please see [What is the difference between an SLR and a DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/35117/15871)